# Can't display dynamically made grid layout

Tags: android, android-layout, grid-layout

Here is my code to create dynamic text views and then create grid layout. But grid layout is not showing

```
TableRow[] tr = new TableRow[arry1.length];
final TextView[] tx = new TextView[arry1.length];
GridLayout tl = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
tl.setRowCount(arry1.length*2);
tl.setColumnCount(1);
final Button but = new Button(S1.this);
b.setText("hi");

GridLayout[] gl = new GridLayout[arry1.length];

for (i = 0; i < arry1.length; i++) {

final String cat = arry1[i].toString();

tx[i] = new TextView(S1.this);
tx[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tx[i].setAllCaps(true);
tx[i].setTextSize(15);
tx[i].setText(cat);

gl[i] = new GridLayout(S1.this);
gl[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

gl[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

tr[i] = new TableRow(S1.this);
tr[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
tr[i].addView(tx[i],new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));            

tl.addView(tr[i],new GridLayout.LayoutParams());    
tl.addView(gl[i], new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
tx[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

 category_main = cat;
     gl[i].addView(but);        // Exception        
    }
});

}
```

when i run above code it shows me text views but it doesn't shows me grid layout and even the button.

Even if i don't add button in grid layout then also grid layout is not shown.

Exception is thrown when i add button to dynamically made grid layout

please help me.

Comment: Maybe you should use TableLayout to add TableRow objects to, instead of GridLayout?

Comment: Well, first of all, what exception does it throw? What does it say?

Comment: when we add grid layout in table layout it will unfortunately stop app

Comment: You add tablerow to tablelayout, not a gridlayout

Comment: @Smokez I have tried that. But i also want to add grid view or grid layout beneath every text view.